# Unable to print out generator as a list

Tags: python-2.7, list, generator

I made a sample generator which behaves as it should giving me the right outcome, but whenever I try to print it in this case, 6, iterations, it prints out only one, and randomly. I want all 6, as if I were making a list in the same format. Thanks!

Here is the code:

```
import random

names = ['Mike', 'John', 'Tom', 'Bill', 'Ted']
majors = ['Math', 'CS', 'Chem', 'History', 'Arts']

def people_generator(num_people):
    for i in xrange(num_people):
        person = {
            'id number': i,
            'name': random.choice(names),
            'major': random.choice(majors)
        }
        yield person

folk = people_generator(6)
print list(folk)
```

Comment: Format your code.

Comment: It gives you list of dict as result and for people_generator(6)  it is giving 6 dicts in the list. Then What output are you expecting?

Comment: yield was outside the loop as Vadim pointed out, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you have the `yield` statement outside the `for` loop - as a result, the generator returns only the last `person`. Placing the statement inside the loop will fix the problem.

Comment: Answered before the question was properly formatted. The formatted code does not have the stated problem.